# Summing a Product in Excel, over the same parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been struggling with something in excel which is quite easy to do individual cases of using an array, but I want to do in a single cell.

Effectively, in row C I have the multipliers I need, lets call them `i_k`, for j from 1 to n. The equation I want to calculate in mathematical notation is;

```
Sigma(from j = 0 to n) (Pi(from k = j to n) (i_k))
```

But I'm not quite sure how best to go about this. Effectively it should be;

```
(i_1)^n + (i_2)^(n-1) + (i_3)^(n-2) + ...
```

In the end. Any help?

Comment: A table / screenshot showing example data would help here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is an elegant solution but I think this might solve it for you.

The key is to make a table so that your formulas continue.

The screenshot I have taken explains the formula I have used with its explanation I have used on top of it.

-- The first column will have the intended values of I
-- The second column's first row will have the value of N
-- The third column will have a formula which says:

> =IF(ISNUMBER([@[Values of N]]),[@[Values of N]],C2-1)

This will give you the decreasing value of N

Now just multiply N with I on the 4th column using a simple multiplication and add the final result:

[image]